# PHP Version in httpd phpinfo.php does not match the command line version

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have an installation of Fedora20.  I have the Apache server and php packages installed using yum.  When i run the command line:

```
php -version i get:
[root@host ~]# php -version
PHP 5.5.20 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2014 05:55:32)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
[root@host ~]#
```

however when i go to

```
http://host/phpinfo.php I get the following version:

PHP logo
PHP Version 5.5.10
```

I have run an md5 sum on libphp5.so and libphp5-zts.so.

```
[root@host modules]# md5sum libphp5.so
05687868a52f9f20960e8471fd10ebce  libphp5.so
[root@host modules]# md5sum libphp5-zts.so
4a16156ba70db7e13cd6722618332c46  libphp5-zts.so
[root@host  modules]#
```

I have compared them to an install that works fine and reports the version as the same for both apache and command line.

```
[root@host modules]# cd /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/
[root@host conf.modules.d]# ls
00-base.conf  00-lua.conf  00-proxy.conf  00-systemd.conf  10-php.conf
00-dav.conf   00-mpm.conf  00-ssl.conf    01-cgi.conf      README
[root@host conf.modules.d]# more 10-php.conf
#
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule !prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

[root@host conf.modules.d]#
```

I have the run yum update as well.

I am at a complete loss as to where to look next.  What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an update:  ran yum info php-cli

```
[root@host ~]# yum info php-cli
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Installed Packages
Name        : php-cli
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.5.20
Release     : 2.fc20
Size        : 13 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : Command-line interface for PHP
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP and Zend and BSD
Description : The php-cli package contains the command-line interface
            : executing PHP scripts, /usr/bin/php, and the CGI interface.
```

It appears to be 5.5.20

Comment: `apachectl restart`?

Comment: yes i did a restart several times.

Comment: Then uninstalling and reinstalling all PHP related packages may be the easiest next step with a high probability of success.

Answer (score 1):

There is a yum package called php-cli which is different from the standard php package apache uses.

Try `$ yum info php-cli` and see what it says. You may need to uninstall that and force install the desired version.

Comment: I updated the question with the yum info php-cli.  it appears to be the same version as everything else (5.5.20)